# How to create a slideshow with drag drop clones

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools, lightgallery

I want to create a page where the user can choose the images that will be shown in a slideshow. I am attempting to use mootools drag and drop and would like to use lightgallery.js.

How can I pass an array of dropped images into the dynamicEL? 
Is there a way to load the images using the id/class of #cart.item?

Any help is greatly appreciated. And apologies in advance for being new at coding.

Here is a codepen that only seems to be slightly working  http://codepen.io/ssab/pen/QGyKVO

```
$(function() {


  jQuery('#dynamic').on('click', function() {
  var selected_image = [];
  jQuery( "#cart.item img" ).each(function() {
  var item1 = {
    src: $(this).find('img').attr('src'),
    thumb: $(this).find('img').attr('data-thumb'),
    subHtml: '<h4></h4>'
  };
   selected_image.push(item1);
});


jQuery(this).lightGallery({
  dynamic: true,
  dynamicEl: selected_image
})
});

 });


var drop = $('cart');
var dropFx = drop.effect('background-color', {wait: false}); // wait is     needed so that to toggle the effect,

$$('.item').each(function(item){

item.addEvent('mousedown', function(e) {
    e = new Event(e).stop();

    var clone = this.clone()
        .setStyles(this.getCoordinates()) // this returns an object with     left/top/bottom/right, so its perfect
        .setStyles({'opacity': 0.7, 'position': 'absolute'})
        .addEvent('emptydrop', function() {
            this.remove();
            drop.removeEvents();
        }).inject(document.body);

    drop.addEvents({
        'drop': function() {
            drop.removeEvents();
            clone.remove();
            item.clone().inject(drop);
            dropFx.start('7389AE').chain(dropFx.start.pass('ffffff', dropFx));
        },
        'over': function() {
            dropFx.start('98B5C1');
        },
        'leave': function() {
            dropFx.start('ffffff');
        }
    });

    var drag = clone.makeDraggable({
        droppables: [drop]
    }); // this returns the dragged element

    drag.start(e); // start the event manual
});

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can launch light box in two ways.

1. when dropping item you can populate array for `dynamicEl`, or
2. when dynamic button clicked create array of elements.

Here option 2 implemented:
http://codepen.io/imranweb7/pen/zorRLG?editors=1111
The logic behind this implementations as per as the html you copied to dropped area.

Please let me know for any explanations.

Comment: Yes! This is great!